# Should you let your manager know before taking vacation time?

Tags: time-off

Personally, I have always let my manager know when I plan to take vacation. Whether it's a single day off or a two week summer vacation, I have always run it by them before officially putting in my PTO. It felt like the courteous thing to do.

When I moved into management, I noticed this isn't necessarily standard practice for everyone. It's not a huge deal because I am an advocate of flexible schedules and encourage everyone to take the time off that they need. But admittedly, I was sort of surprised that my direct reports didn't let me know in advance.

Which practice is more common? Letting your manager know or not?

Additional notes:

- this is US based company
- we have a system where employees must log their vacation time. This system does send the manager a notice
- it appears their peers (team members they work closely with on projects) are given notice so no one on a particular project is left in the dark

Comment: Seems like it would just be common courtesy to let people know when you won't be available. In the small sample size of places I've worked at, it's always been required to let someone know when you are taking off, whether it's an hour or several weeks.

Comment: They don't let you know and just don't show up for work? At what stage do they tell you they have taken vacation?

Comment: If you want to be a responsible employee. Yes you should let your manager know if you're taking time off. I let my manager know when I have a dentist appointment a few days out.

Comment: Can you edit in a country? Where I worked so far, my manager had to sign off on my paperwork. So there was no way to get days off without my manager knowing.

Comment: @dan-klasson they don't let me know in advance. We have a system where employees enter their vacation time so I get an automated notification when they put in their time off. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @nvoigt I added some points for additional context

Comment: This seems like a technical problem. In other words, the reason they're not letting you know is mostly because there is already a system in place. If that system is not notifying you, it could be your fault. After all, what calendaring system doesn't have a notification system in place? or some sort of way to view the calendar in question? In any case, maybe you should just tell them that the system doesn't notify you and to just give you a heads up when they're planning to go on vacation. In any case, yes, it's unusual. They should just tell you. Most workers in the US do tell their manager.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I can see how I wasn’t clear. I did get the automated notifications. I just found it surprising that I didn’t get a personal communication (verbal or email).

Comment: I am genuinely confused as to what exactly the problem is... Your reports are presumably aware that when they enter their PTO into the system that you will be notified. What more would be achieved by them contacting you directly in addition to this? I'm assuming that once you receive the notification that you still have the option to approve or deny the PTO?

Comment: @brhans I’m not arguing it’s a problem. I’m wondering what expectations are for others. For me personally, I had always let my manager know in addition to the automated system and the fact that this wasn’t the case for others had me wondering if it’s the new norm.

Comment: Do you get the automated notifications BEFORE they leave, or when they enter their time?  It is normal to let a manager know ahead of time, so they can schedule work appropriately.  But if you get the notifications when they request the time, you are finding out ahead of time.  If you get the notifications a half hour before they are gone for two weeks, that's a lot different.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek good point. I get the notification when they put the request in, which is usually well in advance. This seems adequate and maybe my own practice of doing both (telling my manager + putting in the system request) was overkill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think at least one of the following is happening here:

- Your direct reports are fairly new to the workplace and not yet accustomed to office norms.
- Your direct reports aren't used to having a formal system for requesting time off and assumed this replaced talking to you directly about it.
- In advocating people take time off when needed, you inadvertently gave the impression that it wasn't important to run it by you first.
- Someone told them they didn't need to do both.
- They've had a manager prior to you explicitly tell them they didn't need/want a separate message about taking time off and they think this is the norm.

Since it sounds like *none* of your direct reports are letting you know first, it wouldn't hurt to ask a couple of other managers how they handle PTO requests. But I don't think you're going to get much push back on this if you just ask them to do it.

Comment: And draw attention to "letting you know" vs " being approved by you". You want to know so you can plan better, but you are not going to block their vacation time. A lot of people equate informing with request for authorization.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the culture of your workplace and how their taking time off affects you. For instance, where I work, I'm mostly responsible for finding and prioritizing my own work, and all my work is delivered to people besides my manager. I always tell the people involved in my projects when I'm taking time off, but I don't always tell my manager if it's just a day or two. It doesn't affect him, no action is required by him, it's unlikely he'd even know I was gone until he sees my timesheet, so why bother him with it?

I've also worked at another place where everything was done through the computer, and I'd only talk to a manager about PTO requests if they didn't approve it promptly or if I thought I might need to convince them to approve it. They knew to check for requests and deal with them, so personally telling them about it often came across as pestering.

I never had a manager say anything about how I requested PTO at either of those places, so presumably none of them minded.  So yes, it *can* be reasonable and normal behavior to not personally tell a manager about PTO requests. I absolutely wouldn't take it as a sign of disrespect, if that's your concern.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're the manager in the scenario, I would say that it'd be common courtesy for them to tell you when they're planning on taking time off.

Your company may have **formal** HR policies about notice for longer periods of time off; that is to say, even if your DRs give a day or two notice for time off, if they are gone for a week, that might be too short of notice for you to reassign tasks or set expectations on deliverable timelines.

At the end of the day, though, it's all about common courtesy and trust.  I'm not a manager, but because the nature of my work does mean that my absence would be noticed or questioned, it's important that I inform my teammates and my manager that I'm going to be out.  This way, everyone is in the know and everyone can either set expectations on deliverables, or we're not waiting for them to dial into the call for the first ten minutes of a meeting.

I should note that there is automation in place at my place of work to let my manager know when I'm taking time off.  But, that doesn't make it unreasonable to communicate that out.

Comment: @makato It appears the manager gets a notification when someone books leave through the holiday system. He believes a personal email to follow up is common courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe vacation schedules are in the control of management.  There may be specific labour laws.  The manager is mostly in control of when the employee can take vacation and the manager can decide to pay out the employee for the vacation time instead.

In Saskatchewan, if the employee and manager cannot reach an agreeable vacation schedule, the manager can give 30 days notice to the employee to take week long vacations.

I believe you're allowed to put a stop to employees' unannounced vacation.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a system in place where your manager should have been told about your vacancy, it's obviously possible that they missed it. So it would be polite to tell them before you are gone, even though they should know. When? If you take Wednesday off, you can tell them on Tuesday afternoon "remember I took Wednesday off". Just enough time so if the manager wanted to talk to you about something on Wednesday, they have a chance to do it now. If it's a longer holiday, give a bit more notice. But that is just politeness.

And if you have a manager who is 100% on top of things and would never be surprised by your holiday, then it won't be necessary at all.